# Using VBA to Delete a Row Based on Time in One Column and Value in Another

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a code that will delete a row if column B has "7:00" and column G has "0". I've been messing with the code below and it appears that the code won't recognize "7:00" in column B (which is formatted as h:mm) unless I enter it as " '7:00". Does this have something to do with the formatting of the time value? Is there a better way to accomplish this?

The code I've been trying:

```
Dim N As Long, i As Long
     N = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
     For i = N To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(i, "B") = "7:00" And Cells(i, "G") = "0" Then
            Cells(i, "B").EntireRow.Delete
        End If
     Next i
```

Comment: Yes, Excel sees time as a decimal part of one day.  Use `Cells(i, "B").Text` to test what is being shown in the cell.

Comment: You can try `TimeValue`. Edit: `If Cells(i, "B") = TimeValue("7:00 AM")`

Comment: @KDavis - better tell the OP to put TimeValue on the "7:00" and not Cells(i, "B").

Comment: Also, is `Cells(i, "G")` formatted as a string or a number? If it's the latter, I would remove the quotation marks around the 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you.

```
If Cells(i, "B").Text = "7:00" And Cells(i, "G").Text = "0" Then
    Cells(i, "B").EntireRow.Delete
End If
```